# CSS only grid layout

Tags: css, grid, css-float, html-lists

I am currently trying to create a grid-layout with HTML/CSS only for various of reasons (I know Bootstrap etc. but that's no option in this context & and I can not add markup elements).

I have the following code (container div with each time a title which has an ul with li's):

```
<div>
  <h3>title here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
    <li>list-item</li>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 2 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 3 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I'd like to be able to create a grid-layout. Meaning e.g. each title is 33% width so I can have 3 next to eachother.

Problem is that there is an ul in between each time. So is there a possible floating solution so I can have a grid layout as result.

```
TITLE   -    TITLE   -    TITLE
  ul           ul           ul
```

-

```
h3 {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul{
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and all of this without a framework.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can set fixed sizes it might be possible (I'll give it a try), if not, then there has to be a wrapper around each group ... or you will need a script, which will be somewhat tricky to come up with.

Comment: Fixed sizes should be OK, I can still re-edit them with CSS-only approach by using mediaqueries then

Comment: The amount of groups also needs to be known, is that possible?

Comment: Give it a go, I can see what I can do with it afterwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample using the existing markup

*Do note they flow from top to bottom, not left to right.*

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 220px;              /*  30px + 80px times 2 row */
}
div > * {
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>title here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
    <li>list-item</li>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 2 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 3 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 2 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 3 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>list-item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

Updated based on a comment

There is one possibility to do a left-to-right build, visually, by using the `order` property

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 220px;              /*  30px + 80px times 2 row */
}
div > * {
  width: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  height: 80px;
}
div :nth-child(3),
div :nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}
div :nth-child(5),
div :nth-child(6) {
  order: 4;
}
div :nth-child(7),
div :nth-child(8) {
  order: 1;
}
div :nth-child(9),
div :nth-child(10) {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>title 1 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>1 list-item</li>
    <li>1 list-item</li>
    <li>1 list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 2 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>2 list-item</li>
    <li>2 list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 3 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>3 list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 4 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>4 list-item</li>
    <li>4 list-item</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>title 5 here</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>5 list-item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance for this to not be build Top-down but being build left-right

Comment: @Kemagezien Will have a look later today... let you know

Comment: @Kemagezien No, with existing markup it is not possible to make it build left-right, but if you can run a script you could wrap each group, and then it can be built left-right

Comment: @Kemagezien Well, there is one way, though if you have many items it will be tedious to maintain, added a sample to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/jw22Lqgo/

```
h3 {
display: inline-block;
}

ul{
 display: block;
}

.col {
width: 32%;
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
}

.container {
width: 960px;
}
```

Comment: I set width:32% and not 33% because when adding the border, it is taking some extra space and it cant fit the whole width container.

Comment: This is indeed what I am trying to achieve but however, I am not able to add a 'col' around each set of h3 and ul.

Comment: Ooh, you can't add markups? dang, Im trying to find another solution then. But Im afraid you can't get rid of these extra .col if you plan to separate those...